# network radio and television

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Does **"network radio and television"** in the following text mean simply radio and television channels or internet-based radio and television?

Context:

> The vast network of global media, including print media, television,
>   and the internet, is another key component of contemporary globalism.
>   This network cements large US, European, and Japanese corporations’
>   control of the release and dissemination of information, one outcome
>   of the deregulation of **network radio and television** in these
>   countries. This deregulation began in the US in the 1970s and was
>   mostly enacted during the Reagan administration in the 1980s, when the
>   Federal Communications Commission’s regulatory power was considerably
>   curtailed ([source](https://books.google.nl/books?id=luS97efEY10C&pg=PA190&lpg=PA190&dq=%22one%20outcome%20of%20the%20deregulation%20of%20network%20radio%20and%20television%20in%20these%20countries%22&source=bl&ots=GH5AXycDQz&sig=DmqU8OTaNGh2762anak0ekwlQMU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj88ImahvDYAhWKK8AKHZNkCBMQ6AEIJzAA#v=onepage&q=%22one%20outcome%20of%20the%20deregulation%20of%20network%20radio%20and%20television%20in%20these%20countries%22&f=false)).

Comment: There were no commercial internet-based media in those decades. Yes, there was life before Youtube and Facebook!

Comment: To KarlG's point Internet media wasn't a factor before the 1990s.  *Network radio and tv* in the US is a reference to the dominance of three networks-ABC, CBS and NBC-before cable. Each country in the developed world had different dominating networks, e.g., in the UK, the BBC. Sweeping statements such as *The vast network of global media* should be regarded as suspect since 'global' in this case is a reference **only** to the developed world. India, China and the bulk of the African continent comprise more than 50% of the world's pop and were not (and are not) subject to this 'global network'

Comment: This seem odd to me: "the deregulation of network radio and television": the deregulation of radio and television networks. It sounds like the person is very young. Television networks,  yes, network television, yes (ABC, CBS, NBC) but not: network radio, please.

Comment: I am only finding: network radio system: http://blog.commarts.wisc.edu/2015/06/24/teaching-radios-history/

Comment: @Lambie et al "Television news in the United States was born of network radio" (see [News, Network](http://www.museum.tv/eotv/newsnetwork.htm))

Answer (score 2):

Because of the time frame involved the writer refers to [over-the-air](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/over-the-air) broadcast networks.
The first such radio networks were [NBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NBC) in the US and [BBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BBC) in the UK, developing in the 1920's. Radio networks were joined with television networks in the 1940's. Audiences mostly abandoned radio in favor of television in the decades after television appeared. However the BBC still has radio listeners for various programs and in the US [NPR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NPR) has a strong audience.
Broadcast networks provide national or regional programming for local broadcast stations.
As the writer referred to deregulation in the 1970's, the writer had to be  referring to broadcast networks, as they were the only network providers then.

Since the rise of the internet, much programming is accessed directly by the audience without the need for a local supplier.

Answer (score 0):

Network radio and television does refer simply to radio and TV channels, but it's slightly more specific than that. Local stations broadcasting from a single location usually aren't included in this definition. Large operations at the state or national level tend to involve many channels, broadcasting locations and content providers - this system is the *network* that we refer to in network radio and television.

Answer (score -2):

Both of these are local radio and television stations. The most common locals are United States because of it's local radio and television stations, Australia just as 1000+ radio and television stations found in every region

The least common are Japan, thanks to an commercial radio and television stations. and the other, there was NHK as public.

Comment: Welcome to ELU, I don't think this answers OP's question, which asks if the term in this context also includes internet-based radio and television.